How to get data from a diffrent backend service through payload cms
I have some functionalities on a backend service "abc" running which returns me data on https://apigateway/abc?id=1, I want to get this data through payload cms whenever i hit an api https://payloadcms/?id=1 from my ui.
Is this possible?
so far being new to headless cms, i understood that payload cms creates mongodb collections and apis based on folder structure, which returns data from payloads mongodb. i want to be able to use both payloads data & apis and my old backend service's data & api

Why do you want to do this? To hide the requests to apigateway? It looks like you need reverse proxy, doing this with a specific app server (payloadcms) is a waste of resources, even if it's capable of this, which I cannot confirm

i want to be able to use multitenant functionality of payload for my apis, so that users can access or not access certain api based on their role or organization.
i don't want to create all the db schemas and api logic in payload cms from the scratch.

The question doesn't say anything  about this. If you need to use payload's auth for other requests then you possibly need this https://payloadcms.com/docs/authentication/using-middleware , "You can make full use of Payload's built-in authentication within your own custom Express endpoints by adding Payload's authentication middleware." You can do anything you need in custom routes, including the requests to other api

If you are looking to manipulate data in a field that doesn't affect the database, then Payload virtual fields are the way to go. I've used the technique in https://payloadcms.com/blog/learn-how-virtual-fields-can-help-solve-common-cms-challenges to achieve this. You could put the API call into the afterRead hook or something like that.
